# bring down a spring boot service when no load and come up when request come

Tags: spring, automation, scale, gateway, orchestration

is there any way that spring-boot application goes down when there is no request and come up a request come? I know there has to be orchestration service. but is there is a way in spring boot? is there any code reference where a light spring boot application there? maybe by gateway etc.

Answer (score 0):

That is an excellent use case for services like AWS lambda and its analogues on other cloud platforms. You can also make an application using Spring Cloud Function and deploy it for example to above mentioned service. As far as I know it would start up the application only when the request arrives and shut it down after it. You can see a tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function
Not sure if that is what you want, let me know if that helps!